# Python convert C header file to dict

Tags: python, file, parsing, dictionary, block

I have a C header file which contains a series of classes, and I'm trying to write a function which will take those classes, and convert them to a python dict. A sample of the file is down the bottom.

Format would be something like

```
class CFGFunctions {
  class ABC {
    class AA {
      file = "abc/aa/functions"
      class myFuncName{ recompile = 1; };
    };
    class BB
    {
      file = "abc/bb/functions"
      class funcName{
        recompile=1;
      }
    }
  };
};
```

I'm hoping to turn it into something like

```
{CFGFunctions:{ABC:{AA:"myFuncName"}, BB:...}}
# Or
{CFGFunctions:{ABC:{AA:{myFuncName:"string or list or something"}, BB:...}}}
```

In the end, I'm aiming to get the filepath string (which is actually a path to a folder... but anyway), and the class names in the same class as the file/folder path.

I've had a look on SO, and google and so on, but most things I've found have been about splitting lines into dicts, rather then n-deep 'blocks'

I know I'll have to loop through the file, however, I'm not sure the most efficient way to convert it to the dict.
I'm thinking I'd need to grab the outside class and its relevant brackets, then do the same for the text remaining inside.

If none of that makes sense, it's cause I haven't quite made sense of the process myself haha

If any more info is needed, I'm happy to provide.

The following code is a quick mockup of what I'm sorta thinking...
It is most likely **BROKEN** and probably does **NOT WORK**. but its sort of the process that I'm thinking of

```
def get_data():
    fh = open('CFGFunctions.h', 'r')
    data = {}    # will contain final data model

    # would probably refactor some of this into a function to allow better looping
    start = ""   # starting class name
    brackets = 0 # number of brackets
    text= ""     # temp storage for lines inside block while looping
    for line in fh:
        # find the class (start
        mt = re.match(r'Class ([\w_]+) {', line)
        if mt:
            if start == "":
                start = mt.group(1)
            else:
                # once we have the first class, find all other open brackets
                mt = re.match(r'{', line)
                if mt:
                    # and inc our counter
                    brackets += 1
                mt2 = re.match(r'}', line)
                if mt2:
                    # find the close, and decrement
                    brackets -= 1
                    # if we are back to the initial block, break out of the loop
                    if brackets == 0:
                        break
                text += line
    data[start] = {'tempText': text}
```

====

Sample file

```
class CfgFunctions {
    class ABC {
        class Control {
            file = "abc\abc_sys_1\Modules\functions";
            class assignTracker {
                description = "";
                recompile = 1;
            };

            class modulePlaceMarker {
                description = "";
                recompile = 1;
            };
        };

        class Devices
        {
            file = "abc\abc_sys_1\devices\functions";
            class registerDevice { recompile = 1; };
            class getDeviceSettings { recompile = 1; };
            class openDevice { recompile = 1; };
        };
    };
};
```

EDIT:
If possible, if I have to use a package, I'd like to have it in the programs directory, not the general python libs directory.

Comment: use something like [`pycparser`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycparser) to parse it into an AST and then it's (reasonably) straightforward from there.

Comment: you wish to make it like LISP lang.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions :) 
 
Slightly off topic, do you know if its possible to 'install' the package in the same directory as the project? (instead of the python libs file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you detected, parsing is necessary to do the conversion. Have a look at the package PyParsing, which is a fairly easy-to-use library to implement parsing in your Python program.

Edit: This is a very symbolic version of what it would take to recognize a **very** minimalistic grammer - somewhat like the example at the top of the question. It won't work, but it might put you in the right direction:

```
from pyparsing import ZeroOrMore, OneOrMore, \
                      Keyword, Literal


test_code = """
class CFGFunctions {
  class ABC {
    class AA {
      file = "abc/aa/functions"
      class myFuncName{ recompile = 1; };
    };
    class BB
    {
      file = "abc/bb/functions"
      class funcName{
        recompile=1;
      }
    }
  };
};
"""

class_tkn       = Keyword('class')
lbrace_tkn      = Literal('{')
rbrace_tkn      = Literal('}')
semicolon_tkn   = Keyword(';')
assign_tkn      = Keyword(';')

class_block     = ( class_tkn + identifier + lbrace_tkn + \
                    OneOrMore(class_block | ZeroOrMore(assignment)) + \
                    rbrace_tkn + semicolon_tkn \
                  )

def test_parser(test):
    try:
        results = class_block.parseString(test)
        print test, ' -> ', results
    except ParseException, s:
        print "Syntax error:", s


def main():
    test_parser(test_code)

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, this code is only the parser - it does *not* generate any output. As you can see in the PyParsing docs, you can later add the actions you want. But the first step would be to recognize the what you want to translate.

And a last note: Do not underestimate the complexities of parsing code... Even with a library like PyParsing, which takes care of much of the work, there are many ways to get mired in infinite loops and other amenities of parsing. Implement things step-by-step!

EDIT: A few sources for information on PyParsing are:

http://werc.engr.uaf.edu/~ken/doc/python-pyparsing/HowToUsePyparsing.html

http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/

(Particularly interesting is http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Publications, with a long list of articles - several of them introductory - on PyParsing)

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing_helper is a GUI for debugging parsers

There is also a 'tag' Pyparsing here on stackoverflow, Where Paul McGuire (the PyParsing author) seems to be a frequent guest.

*** NOTE: ***
From PaulMcG in the comments below: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to [github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing](http://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)
Makes things a lot clearer!

Slightly off topic, do you know if its possible to 'install' the package in the same directory as the project? (instead of the python libs file)

Comment: One thing I'll say is that its documentation is crap and/or almost non-existant

Comment: 'Installing' packages in Python, using the standard way of things, will install it in the /usr/pythonX.XX/site-packages directory. It is however possible to install the package in your own directory using `python setup.py install --user`

Comment: Thanks! 
Now I just needa deal with the issue of no documentation xD
 To google!

Comment: I've added a list of information sources to the answer above.

Comment: Thanks!
Most the documentation stuff on that pyparsing wiki site was like "please buy this book to learn about it"
Will have a look at those links :)

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing